# what are the attributes that pthreads share and don't share among themselves

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I am a newbee to linux. Right now I am following "Advanced Linux book"

I know when we create a new thread from a process, it gets inherited from the main thread of the process.

Let's say I created a thread pt1 from pt. Then pt1 inherits the environment,code,signal mask.
The only thing that it doesn't share is "set of pending of signals" for the new thread is cleared.

I want to know what more attributes are not shared between the threads of the same process.

Any help is thankful

Comment: Can anyone provide some more valuable answers??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads in the same process share:

```
  Process instructions
  Most data
  open files (descriptors)
  signals and signal handlers
  current working directory
  User and group id
```

Each thread has a unique:

```
  Thread ID
  set of registers, stack pointer
  stack for local variables, return addresses
  signal mask
  priority
```